# Uploading multiple files directly to S3 in Laravel with fine uploader

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to use the [Fine Uploader](https://blog.fineuploader.com) package to upload multiple files to my S3 Bucket in my laravel project.

I have implemented the [Example Controller](https://github.com/FineUploader/php-laravel-s3-server) that has been provided but the uploads fail and i have spent hours trying to work out why

i get the following errors

```
Successfully parsed some EXIF tags
POST http://localhost:8000/uploader 419 (unknown status)
POST request for 0 has failed - response code 419
Response does not include the base64 encoded policy!
Policy signing failed.  Response does not include the base64 encoded policy!
Simple upload request failed for 0
```

ROUTE

```
Route::post('/uploader', 'S3UploadController@endpoint')->name('uploader');
```

Frontend

```
var s3Uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
            debug: true,
            element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader-s3'),
            template: 'qq-template-s3',
            request: {
                endpoint: "BUCKET.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com",
                accessKey: "PUBLIC KEY"
            },
            signature: {
                endpoint: "{{route('uploader')}} "
            },
            uploadSuccess: {
                endpoint: "/uploader?success",
                params: {
                    isBrowserPreviewCapable: qq.supportedFeatures.imagePreviews
                }
            },
              headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
            iframeSupport: {
                localBlankPagePath: "/fine-uploader/success.html"
            },
            cors: {
                expected: false
            },
            chunking: {
                enabled: false
            },
            resume: {
                enabled: true
            },
            deleteFile: {
                enabled: true,
                method: "POST",
                endpoint: "uploader?deleteObject"
            },
            validation: {
                itemLimit: 5,
                sizeLimit: 15000000
            },
            thumbnails: {
                placeholders: {
                    notAvailablePath: "/fine-uploader/not_available-generic.png",
                    waitingPath: "/fine-uploader/waiting-generic.png"
                }
            },
            callbacks: {
                onComplete: function(id, name, response) {
                    var previewLink = qq(this.getItemByFileId(id)).getByClass('preview-link')[0];

                    if (response.success) {
                        previewLink.setAttribute("href", response.tempLink)
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Please help me with this i am going insane :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not manage to get Fine Uploader working so i used PL Upload instead and its working great :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Laravel [File System](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem) approach?

This is more flexible to upload files in either local or s3.

Comment: Yes i have tried using the File System approach  but it is very slow